# Using jQuery to clear certain fields in a WTForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask, wtforms

In a Flask app, I have a form with several fields. There are two submit buttons, one of which is intended to submit only information from fields one and two (even if the other fields contain text).

I reluctantly have decided to try to do this in jQuery, something I don't have much experience in. After considered using the $.post method, I settled on using $.reset.

Here's some of my code:

(home.html)

```
<HEAD>
  <script src="/static/scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js">
  </script>
  <script src="/static/scripts/reset.js">
  </script>
<TITLE>My UI</TITLE>
</HEAD>
```

(separate html file inheriting from home.html)

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <dl>
        foo
        {{ form.foo }}
      bar
      {{ form.bar }}

      <form action="/" method="post"><p><input type=submit class="reset" value="Get Information">
        Status
        {{ form.status(class_="reset-this") }}
        other
          {{ form.other(class_="reset-this") }}
        Frequency
          {{ form.frequency(class_="reset-this") }}

  </dl>
  <p><input type=submit value=Update>
```

And finally, my JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("button.reset").click(function() {
      $(".resetThis").val("");
    });
  });
```

It doesn't have any effect, when I run the file, and when I try to simulate it in JSFiddle, I get a `Forbidden (403): CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` error.

Is there something basic I'm missing?

Comment: may we see the fiddle?

Comment: Sure! Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/joshf/g21knp5v/ (The form doesn't render properly here because it's in jinja2, but the "verification failed" error replicates.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your fiddle you have several issues:

1. You lack some serious formatting, you are not closing html tags.
2. You have a form inside another form, why?
3. you are using input `type="submit"` if you want to reset the inputs you have to use `type="button"` otherwise the form will try to submit to whatever you put on `<form action="/">` hence the 403 error
4. you are using `<form action="/">` that does nothing but generate confusion in your case.
5. in the jquery function you are using `$("button.reset")` but in your html you are using `inputs` and never `buttons`.
6. In your jquery function you are trying to use the class `resetThis` but in your html the class is `reset-this`
7. You **did not** attach jquery to your fiddle, it was never gonna work without it.

finally i have refactored [your code here](https://jsfiddle.net/g21knp5v/2/) with all those problems fixed for you to build up from there. but please do some more research when you are trying to implement a technology you are not familiar with.

Comment: Thank you so much for this feedback. I was copying some stuff from a larger project and I think that's where some of the issues came from. In any case this is incredibly helpful!